# Loading Multiple Shared Libraries in Same Process

Tags: java, gcc, linker, osgi, ld

I am running an OSGi application and I have bundles B1 and B2 that use shared libraries S1 and S2 respectively. S1 and S2 have quite a few exported redundant methods. I want both bundles to call methods from their respective shared libraries only (So B1 uses S1 and B2 uses S2).On osx this is the behaviour. But on linux the behavior is different. Both osgi bundles use methods from the sharedlib that is loaded first.I am guessing this is because the shared libs are loaded by the same process.

How can i make sure that each bundle uses methods from its respective shared library only ?

Comment: Can you please explain how you load those libraries?

Comment: System.loadLibrary(); The libraries are included in the bundles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a version of the bundle in the Manifest.MF

Insert into S1 Manifest file

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.S1
```

And into B1 Manifest

```
Import-Package: yourpackage;version="1.0.0.S1"
```

Insert into S2 Manifest file

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.S2
```

And into B2 Manifest

```
Import-Package: yourpackage;version="1.0.0.S2"
```

In this way will use only the packages an classes in S1

Comment: I wouldn't add this to the version. It is possible to declare custom properties for exports and imports, like this: `Import-Package: yourpackage; version="1.0.0"; library=S1`. However, I am not sure if this applies to the OPs question, as I believe he is talking about actual shared libraries (not bundles), as shown be the tags.